# Multi-Site Plugin Activated (Not Network-Activated), What Happens?

Tags: customization, multisite

Hey guys. I am working on a plugin and I am trying to figure out all of the possible scenarios in which the plugin can be used.

I am aware of the new Multi-Site feature. If the plugin is network activated, then it will basically be forced upon all of the blogs within that website. What happens if the plugin is just activated, but not network activated? Does this mean that **it's giving** the user the choice of enabling it? In other words: does activating the plugin mean it will appear in each blog admin's plugin list, allowing them to enable it or not? If this is true, then that means that if the plugin is *not* activated, then it won't show up in each blog admin's plugin list, correct?

So the scenarios are:

1. network activated => forced upon all users
2. activated => each user now has the option to enable it or not
3. disabled => the user won't even see it in their plugin list

Is this correct? Thanks, I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about network activated.

About the other two:
The user will always see all the plugins in their blog admin's plugin list.
Activating a plugin means activating it only on the current blog, and you can deactivate it if it was previously enabled. These two options does not affect the other blogs in the network, only the current one.

More details here: http://premium.wpmudev.org/wpmu-and-buddypress-plugins/activating-and-deactivating-regular-plugins/